# What's the verb for keeping something warm with one's body?

Tags: word-request

You know I am looking for a verb that roughly means "keep something warm with one's body". It's not a general-use word, because it mostly applies to certain animals. Let me give you an example:

> The hen ___ the eggs to keep them warm.

I don't think it's a verb you can use for human beings, and I don't think there's a verb that applies for human beings, but I would be curious to know if there's a general-use word.

Answer (score 1):

There is no English word specifically for this.  "Warm" by itself is a verb for "make warm" but it doesn't specify how.

> The bread has been sitting around for a while so you can **warm** it in the oven before you serve it.

There is a word meaning "to keep eggs warm until they hatch", and that is *incubate*

> The hen **incubates** her eggs by sitting on them.